# Why am I getting an ""Object" does not contain a definition for "Index"" error?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, selectedindexchanged

I've looked and looked but I can't seem to find any solution to this problem so I decided I might as well ask.

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZoDmeAZAD8) to help me create an address book in C# using WinForms. I've created the GUI, and the "Person" class that holds it all together, and I can add entries just fine. But when I write the code to switch between them, following what's written in the tutorial, I get this error message:

"object" does not contain a definition for "Index" and no extension method "Index" accepting a first argument of type "object" could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is my code for the "SelectedIndexChanged" event. It's slightly different from the tutorial: I'm putting "entryList.SelectedItems[0].Index" into a pre-defined int "i" to save writing it out eight times, my GUI is rather different, and I defined the list of Person objects in a separate "Methods" class for various reasons. The basic principle is the same though, so I don't see why mine flags up an error and his doesn't.

```
        private void entryList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   //set the text boxes to display the data in the selected entry
        if (entryList.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            i = entryList.SelectedItems[0].Index;
            nameText.Text = Methods.list[i].Name;
            birthDay.Text = Methods.list[i].BirthDay.ToString();
            birthMonth.Text = Methods.list[i].BirthMonth.ToString();
            birthYear.Text = Methods.list[i].BirthYear.ToString();
            numberText1.Text = Methods.list[i].NumberPart1;
            numberText2.Text = Methods.list[i].NumberPart2;
            addressText.Text = Methods.list[i].Address;
            eMailText.Text = Methods.list[i].Email;
        }
    }
```

It's the ".Index" part that's flagging up the error and I don't know why. So, where have I gone wrong?

EDIT: Just to clarify, I have tried various workarounds such as

```
i = entryList.SelectedIndex;
```

but those still won't let me switch between the items in the ListBox, it keeps displaying whatever the last one I entered was.

EDIT 2: More info as requested by Rotem. Here's the code for adding an entry, this adds it to a list of Person objects which is kept in the separate Methods class for various reasons (hence Methods.list). It also adds the person's name to the ListBox list, and in theory, I then want to be able to switch between viewing different entries by clicking the names in the ListBox, which is what the first code segment is for. Except that's not working.

```
        private void newEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   //creates a new entry, displaying its data in the appropriate fields, and then saves it
        Person p = new Person(nameText.Text, Convert.ToByte(birthDay.Text), Convert.ToByte(birthMonth.Text), Convert.ToInt16(birthYear.Text), numberText1.Text, numberText2.Text, addressText.Text, eMailText.Text);
        Methods.list.Add(p);
        entryList.Items.Add(p.Name);
        nameText.Text = " ";
        birthDay.Text = "DD";
        birthMonth.Text = "MM";
        birthYear.Text = "YYYY";
        numberText1.Text = " ";
        numberText2.Text = " ";
        addressText.Text = " ";
        eMailText.Text = " ";
    }
```

EDIT 3: As requested, here's the code for the "Person" class:

```
class Person
{
    private static string name;
    private static byte birthDay;
    private static byte birthMonth;
    private static short birthYear;
    private static string numberPart1;
    private static string numberPart2;
    private static string address;
    private static string email;

    //encapsulation goes here...

    public Person(string a, byte b, byte c, short d, string e, string f, string g, string h)
    {
        name = a;
        if (b <= 31 && c <= 12 && d < DateTime.Now.Year)
        {
            birthDay = b;
            birthMonth = c;
            birthYear = d;
        }
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid date of birth");
        numberPart1 = e;
        numberPart2 = f;
        address = g;
        email = h;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in `entryList` is a `ListBox`, then it's items are only `object`s, they are not some data structure that keeps track of the index (unlike, for example, `ListView` items, which have an `Index` property).

Instead, you can use the [`SelectedIndices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindices%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the `ListBox`.

```
int i = entryList.SelectedIndices[0];
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't give me an error, but it still won't switch between the objects in the ListBox.

Comment: @F1Krazy We'd need to see the relevant parts of your code then. What is `entryList` and what is `Methods.list`? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Okay, I'll add those.

Comment: @F1Krazy This would be a great opportunity to start using breakpoints in your debugging process. In fact, that's probably the biggest value you could get from this experience. Set a break point right after this line and see (1) that the code actually enters that part, and (2) what is the value you get for `i` and `Methods.list[i]` in that part.

Comment: @Rotem That's the best advice for a situation like this. There's so many questions where I want to tell the OP that. A basic understanding of the debugger and how to use it would remove half the questions on this site.

Comment: According to the debug, i is being properly set to 0 when I select the first item in the list, and 1 when I select the second item. So that part of the problem works, it's just not changing what's in the text boxes apparently.

Comment: @F1Krazy Break one line later, and hover your mouse over `Methods.list[i]` (assuming you're using Visual Studio). Is the value that is returned the value you'd expect?

Comment: Methods.list[i] is returning the right value (o if I select the first name in the list, and so on) but Methods.list[i].Name is still returning the name of whoever was last entered and not the name of whoever I selected.

Comment: @F1Krazy That sounds somewhat contradictory. Post the code for `Person` if you still don't find the problem.

Comment: I'll do that in just a second.

Comment: Ah, there we go! All the fields on `Person` are marked `static`!. That means they will be identical on all instances of `Person`. You change one, you change them all.

Comment: Ah, I see! Can't believe I made such a stupid mistake xD I still get muddled up with static and not-static fields sometimes. Thanks! I'll fix that and then in theory everything should work out fine.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
i = entryList.SelectedIndex
```

That should take the index from the listbox, as long as it matches your list you should be ok.